# JavaFX: Position of label not matching up with position of drag button in slider

Tags: java, javafx, slider

There is a slider and a label in my scene. I've written an anonymous method that will set the text of the label according to the value of the slider and then place it directly under slider's drag-button.

```
timeSlider.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {

            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
                final double timeSliderMin = timeSlider.getMin();
                timeLabel.setText(String.valueOf(newValue.intValue()));
                timeLabel.setLayoutX(timeSlider.getLayoutX() + (timeSlider.getValue() - timeSliderMin)
                        / (timeSlider.getMax() - timeSliderMin) * timeSlider.getWidth());
            }
});
```

In this context, the timeSlider is the slider and the timeLabel is the label that I was referring to earlier.

Here are pictures of the misalignment of the label in relation to the slider:
[image]

The picture above shows that when the slider is at the min value, the label is directly under it.
[image]

However, when the slider is at its max value, the label is not even properly aligned with the slider.

I'd really appreciate any insight on what I could possibly be doing wrong for this to occur.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Well you want the text centered on the thumb, so I thought I would try basing the layout of the text on the thumb position, and it worked.

I'm not necessarily recommending a solution like the one below.  There are probably better ways to accomplish this or at least better ways to structure the code to make the labeled slider its own "control", but it was just something I came up with that seemed to get the job done.

Note, I placed the text above the slider because it seemed more usable that way.  Because then, the text was not obscured by the mouse pointer when you dragged the thumb.

The labeled slider idea is actually quite a nice idea by the way.

[image: min]
[image: mid]
[image: max]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.*;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class LabeledSlider extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Text text = new Text();
        text.setTextOrigin(VPos.TOP);
        Slider slider = new Slider(7, 7_700, 4_200) {
            @Override
            protected void layoutChildren() {
                super.layoutChildren();

                Region thumb = (Region) lookup(".thumb");
                if (thumb != null) {
                    text.setLayoutX(
                            thumb.getLayoutX() 
                                    + thumb.getWidth() / 2 
                                    - text.getLayoutBounds().getWidth() / 2
                    );
                }
            }
        };
        slider.setLayoutY(20);
        text.textProperty().bind(slider.valueProperty().asString("%,.0f"));

        Pane sliderPane = new Pane(slider, text);
        slider.prefWidthProperty().bind(sliderPane.widthProperty());
        sliderPane.setPrefWidth(200);

        StackPane layout = new StackPane(sliderPane);
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        stage.setScene(new Scene(layout));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, I've tried your approach and it works well when dragging - but when it comes to clicking on the slider, the label seems to lag behind and only changes upon clicking again.

Comment: I don't experience any lag on clicking on the slider.  When I do so, the label moves to the correct spot an updates its value immediately on clicking (test system Java 8u60, OS X 10.11.4, MacBook Air 2012).

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me as if your label and text is left-alligned. Try to center it and see what the difference is.